# OS X El Capitan Disk Utilities First Aid Fails - Now What?

Tags: macos

The system is seemingly running fine, yet a recommended First Aid repair failed. What's my next step? I Googled this deeply and couldn't find a current, relevant pointer. Any tips appreciated!

Comment: How did it fail? What was the error message, if any?  Maybe add a snippet of the Disk Utility Log to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have a good answer. The problem went away when I was trying to collect more data.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Knowing some issues are  transient is actually a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty light on details but generally speaking when this happens you should boot into recovery mode (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>) when booting the Mac and go into Disk Utility and try to repair from there.

Failing that you may have to go with a 3rd-party disk repair tool. My go-to is DiskWarrior, there are others that work well too.

Comment: I did go to DiskUtility in recovery mode. That's where the repair failed. But because I was in recovery mode I didn't know how to collect the specific errors to share here. Would they have been stored somewhere that I can retrieve them, because I can't find them,,,

Comment: I ran it again in Recovery mode, used my iPhone to take pictures of the messages. ... and the error didn't happen again :)